# Map keyboard shortcut to TFS Get Latest Version (Recursive)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know how I can successfully map a keyboard shortcut to the context menu command **Get Latest Version (Recursive)** which is seen when you right click on the solution in Solution Explorer and have the solution version controlled under TFS?

[image]

Comment: Looks like it was requested quite some time ago, but was never implemented: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2520967-add-a-global-shortcut-to-do-a-get-latest-version-r

Comment: Hi silkfire, there is not any keyboard shortcut command for now. You have to use the workaround below. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for a vote or marking it as an answer, which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not any keyboard shortcut command for now. And there has been a related uservoice and already been closed.

> [Add a global shortcut to do a get latest version recursive on the
>   opened solution](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2520967-add-a-global-shortcut-to-do-a-get-latest-version-r)

If you simply not like to right click and select "Get Latest Version (Recursive)" option to do the get latest in Visual Studio.

Just a kindly remind, **there is also a 'get latest version' icon** (a grey clock with a blue arrow pointing down on it) in the Source Control Explorer's menu bar.

[image: get latest icon]

If an item (a folder or a file) is selected in the Source Control Explorer then clicking the icon will retrieve the latest version from TFS recursively.

Besides, you could use `tf get` command to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use on source control item: "Keyboard Menu Button" then "l"

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested you can try my Visual studio extension: Keyz (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YanivRubinpur.Keyz)

Just press Ctrl K, Ctrl J and it will "get latest" on the entire solution.

I have built it since I didn't find any easy way to bind that command to a keyboard shortcut.